# How to extract colname such that it literally equals to WRITING the variable in R

Tags: r, regression, extract

I want to use the second scenario in order to do a for-loop over some variables. However, since the second approach gives me that certain kind of output, I get an error message for the rest of my script.

How can I write the second regression such that it will give me the output like in the first one?

```
> head(colnames(training))
[1] "Y"    "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4" 

> lm.reg <- lm(Y ~ X1, data = training)
> prob = predict(lm.reg, newdata = test) 
> head(prob)
  Person 1        Person 2       Person 3      Person 4 
  0.128           0.232          0.422         0.784    

> lm.reg <- lm(Y ~ training[, 2], data = training)
> prob = predict(lm.reg, newdata = test) 
> head(prob)
  1         2         3         4         
  0.128     0.232     0.422     0.784
```

I also tried it with `colnames(training)[2]`, but that doesn't work either.

The test dataset looks kinda like this

```
              Y     X1     X2 ... Xn
Person 1      0     1      0
Person 2      0     1      1
Person 3      1     0      0 
... 
Person 294    1     1      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as.formula`

```
> lm.reg <- lm(as.formula(paste0("Y ~ ", colnames(training)[2])), data = training)
> prob = predict(lm.reg, newdata = test) 
> head(prob)
```

Comment: You are a hero. How did you obtain those skills? How did you know, that you have to use `as.formula` and then `paste0`?

Comment: @Textime with time you will acquire these skills. Its easy.